# Is it possible to parse "Fri, 24 Feb 2012 20:00:00 GMT" with using NSDateFormatter?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to parse

```
 Fri, 24 Feb 2012 20:00:00 GMT
```

Is it possible to do this with using NSDateFormatter?

Comment: You can lookup a list of date format strings from http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
NSString *dateString = @"Fri, 24 Feb 2012 20:00:00 GMT";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Depending on how you will specify the time zone, you may have to change the line:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
```

with

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z";
```

if you will use GMT-02:00 for example, but keep it if you will use PDT.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you should use a mask..

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] ];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

It could work.